# Multiple conditions in MongoDB group aggregation

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the documents in the below format. I would like to count production deployments from the collection. Mongo Playground link is also attached here.

A document is considered as a production deployment when ANY of the following is true.

1. deployments.steps.environments.name contains Production OR Prod OR Prd
2. deployments.steps.stages contains Production OR Prod OR Prd

Any help on incorporating the above condition into the query to calculate TotalCount, SucceededCount etc. please?

Update: I have updated the query here. Am I right?

```
    [
  {
    "productId": "613a5114b24382575e7e7668",
    "deployments": [
      {
        "projectId": "613a5083b24382575e7e765f",
        "title": "Release-4",
        "steps": [
          {
            "releaseId": 8168,
            "title": "UnitTest-Release-004",
            "environments": [
              {
                "envId": 61553,
                "name": "Production"
              }
            ],
            "stages": []
          },
          {
            "releaseId": 7376,
            "title": "UnitTest-Release-005",
            "environments": [],
            "stages": [
              "Prod"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-11-03T07:55:57.486Z"),
    "deploymentStatus": "Succeeded",
    "completedAt": ISODate("2021-11-03T07:29:00.907Z"),
    "startedAt": ISODate("2021-11-03T07:26:53.761Z"),
    
  },
  {
    "productId": "613a5114b24382575e7e7668",
    "deployments": [
      {
        "projectId": "613a5083b24382575e7e765f",
        "title": "Release-4",
        "steps": [
          {
            "releaseId": 8168,
            "title": "UnitTest-Release-004",
            "environments": [
              {
                "envId": 61553,
                "name": "Production"
              }
            ],
            "stages": []
          },
          {
            "releaseId": 7376,
            "title": "UnitTest-Release-005",
            "environments": [],
            "stages": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-11-03T07:55:57.486Z"),
    "deploymentStatus": "Failed",
    "completedAt": ISODate("2021-11-03T07:29:00.907Z"),
    "startedAt": ISODate("2021-11-03T07:26:53.761Z"),
    
  }
]
```

Here is the query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "createdAt": {
            $gte: ISODate("2020-11-01")
          }
        },
        {
          "createdAt": {
            $lte: ISODate("2021-11-17")
          }
        }
      ],
      $or: [
        {
          "deployments.steps.environments.name": {
            "$in": [
              "Prd",
              "Prod",
              "Production"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "deployments.steps.stages.name": {
            "$in": [
              "Prd",
              "Prod",
              "Production"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$productId",
      TotalCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      SucceededCount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$deploymentStatus",
                "Succeeded"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      FailedCount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$deploymentStatus",
                "Failed"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      CancelledCount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$deploymentStatus",
                "Cancelled"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      },
      NotStartedCount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $eq: [
                "$deploymentStatus",
                "NotStarted"
              ]
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nKW-_BsmP2r)

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve this.

Comment: I have updated the query with my changes in Mongo Playground.

Comment: Ah, MongoPlayground isn't part of [so]. You need to provide necessary information to answer your question _within your question_ as text, not as an off-site link. You can use MongoPlayground as a _supplemental link_, but it should not form the core of your question.

Answer (score 0):

$cond - if - then - else = without quotes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).